# Dismatched image texture with geometry

Tags: three.js

I have created a planegeometry and a texture which is made by ImageUtils with CanvasRenderer,
and then I created a mesh and finished all relative parameters'settings. The result is that a PlaneGeometry with the image
 texture in the space,but  a **diagonal line** is showed up,what's more, one image are **divided into two 
parts** by this diagonal line,thus **images on this two parts become dismatched**.How should I resolve it? The key code are as follows:

```
    var planeGeo=new THREE.PlaneGeometry(2000,3000);
    var map = THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture( 'images/greenLines.png' );
    map.wrapS=map.wrapT = THREE.RepeatWrapping;
    map.repeat.set(2,2);
    map.anisotropy = 16;
    var planeMaterial=new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({color:0xFFBBEE,map:map,overdraw:true});
    var planeMesh=new THREE.Mesh(planeGeo,planeMaterial);
    planeMesh.position.set(2000,-2000,5000);
    scene.add(planeMesh);
```

**NOTICE**:the images are constructed by green lines.The result displays that lines are cut and one 
line has become two lines which are located on two divided triangles .
**Now how should I modify my code so that the two parts of  this image looks matched well without displacement!
Can the diagonal line be removed?**

Comment: Can you show a screenshot or maybe upload the test somewhere?

Comment: I have no reputation over 10 to upload my picture,but it looks like a issue of #809 at "https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/issues/809".I don't want to add segments because of its consuming memory.